# Change theme of existing opencart How complicated

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

We have an existing shopping cart in opencart with third party theme installed.
The cart works fine and it contains around 500+ products listed.We would like to change the existing theme of opencart. Can some open cart experts tell me how complicated it is?Do we need to re upload all products or just to install  a fresh theme?
Is there any facility to switch the theme from admin panel?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to re upload the all products. follow the steps:

1. Download the theme.(must supported with opencart and extension must be 
   ".")
2. just need to install theme package in

   > extension -> installer

   of opencart.
3. After successful installation of theme just goto

   > extension -> modification

   and click the refresh button.
4. Go to

   > system -> settings

   edit your store and you will find the option to select another themes.

Note: Please read the documentation to better understand: [Opencart userguide](http://docs.opencart.com/system/setting/store/)